# Passing a formatted NSDate

Tags: objective-c

Formatted dates that I am passing to an instance method are not saving/printing the correct date. Can someone please help?

Calling method code snippets:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-yyyy"];

[requests addObject:[[Request alloc] initWithDueDate:(NSDate *) [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"13-09-2011"]]];
```

Receiving method code snippets:

```
dueDate = dd;

NSLog(@"Due Date: %@", dueDate);
```

Console output:

Due Date: 2011-01-12 13:09:00 +0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check your formatting string. It follows [these](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) official formats.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
```

Small `m` is for minute, cap `M` for the month.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was missing the capitals.

Answer (score 1):

Next works perfect for me:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"13-09-2011"];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Make sure you check your formatted NSDates to this. They are case-sentitive so make sure you use them correctly